# ¿Cómo recuperar id de otra tabla con asp.net y Npsql?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

estoy usando asp.net Core Web API con Npsql, quiero recuperar el id de la tabla dirección para insertarlo en la llave foránea de la tabla empresa.

Lo que intente fue hacer una transacción obteniendo el id con un SELECT MAX y pasar el resulto ala tabla de empresa

'''

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Post(Empresa emp)
    {
        string query = @"
         Begin;
        SELECT MAX(idDireccion) AS @max_id FROM direccion;

            insert into empresa (nombreComercial,logotipo,idDireccion,idClasificacion,estado) 
            values               (@nombreComercial,@logotipo,@max_id,@idClasificacion,true); 

         commit;
        ";
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeAppCon");
        NpgsqlDataReader myReader;
        using (NpgsqlConnection myCon = new NpgsqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
        {
            myCon.Open();
            using (NpgsqlCommand myCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(query, myCon))
            {
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombreComercial", emp.nombreComercial);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logotipo", emp.logotipo);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@max_id", emp.idDireccion);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idClasificacion", emp.idClasificacion);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                table.Load(myReader);
                myReader.Close();
                myCon.Close();
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult("Agregado exitosamente");
    }
```

'''

Comment: Podrías dividir el problema en 2 bloques, uno para obtener el valor máximo del ID y luego con ese mismo valor, se lo entregas en el segundo bloque donde haces la inserción respectiva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 cosas antes que nada:

1- Nunca utilizar Datatables en lugar de eso use fast member : https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member

2-Cuando uno usa using(){} no es necesario llamar el método close() ni para cerrar la conexión a base de datos ni para cerrar  el reader, más bien llamar el método close() cuando se usa el using(){} puede provocar errores.

Puede hacerlo con una función y en lugar de una transacción simplemente bloquea la tabla como en el siguiente ejemplo y si por alguna razón necesita que sea con transacción sin bloquear la tabla entonces simplemente crea un store procedure y llama la función desde el sp en una transacción:

función en postgres:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ingresarempresa(
        pnombrecomercial text,
        plogotipo text,
        pidclasificacion text)
        RETURNS text
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    AS $BODY$
    begin
        Lock table empresa in share mode;
        insert into empresa 
        (nombreComercial,logotipo,idDireccion,idClasificacion,estado)
        values(pnombrecomercial,plogotipo,
        (select max(idDireccion) from direccion),pidclasificacion,true); 
        --éxito
        return 'Agregado exitosamente';
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        --error
        return SQLERRM;
    end;
    $BODY$;
```

Y el controlador quedaría de esta manera :

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Post([FromBody] Empresa emp)
        {
            string? result = "";
            string query = "SELECT ingresarEmpresa(@nombreComercial,@logotipo,@idClasificacion);";
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeAppCon");
           
            using (NpgsqlConnection myCon = new NpgsqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (NpgsqlCommand myCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombreComercial", emp.nombreComercial);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logotipo", emp.logotipo);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idClasificacion", emp.idClasificacion);
                    result = (string?)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult(result);
        }
```